# Edit and Delete on Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can we show DropDown and bind DropDown data based on Id column value(Hidden in GridView) on Edit click on Gridview Using OnRowEditing and RowDataBound events. And this DropDown should not be shown on GridView Load. As i want to select value of colomn1 and pass it to database to get DropDown data, i am using below code on Edit CLick.

```
protected void RowDataBound (object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
                {
                    DropDownList DDL = 
                    (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList2");
                    int editRowIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
                    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[editRowIndex];
                    string Tname = row.Cells[2].Text;// To get value at colomn 2
                    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(cs);
                    cn.Open();
                    SqlCommand cd = new SqlCommand();
                    DataTable dt = cn.GetData("Select TrainingDate from TrainingDetail where TrainingName = Tname");
                    cd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cd.Parameters.Add("@Tname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Tname;
                    cd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cn.Close();

                }
            }


 protected void OnRowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" OnRowEditing="OnRowEditing" OnRowDeleting="OnRowDeleting" OnRowDataBound ="RowDataBound">
            <Columns>
                 <asp:BoundField  DataField ="Id"  HeaderText ="Training Id" Visible="False" InsertVisible ="false" ReadOnly="true" />
                 <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" DataField ="TrainingName"  HeaderText ="Training Name" />
                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Training Date">
                     <EditItemTemplate>
                         <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TrainingDate", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
                     </EditItemTemplate>
                     <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" DataTextField ="TrainingDate" Visible ="false" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                         </asp:DropDownList>
                     </ItemTemplate>
                 </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField  ReadOnly="true" DataField ="TrainingType"  HeaderText ="Training Type" />
            <asp:BoundField  ReadOnly="true" DataField ="TrainingDuration"  HeaderText ="Training Duration(hours)" />
                <asp:BoundField  ReadOnly="true" DataField ="StartTrainingTime"  HeaderText ="Start Training Time" />
                    <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" DataField ="EndTrainingTime"  HeaderText ="End Training Time" />
            </Columns>
                 </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Putting a more detail about the use case you want to implement would be more useful. Also share some code which you already written.

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/editing-data-using-asp-net-gridview-control). It covers all the basics of GridView editing and updating.